# За что в CSS отвечают символы > и ~

Tags: css, веб-программирование

Недавно начал свой путь в веб-разработку.

При просмотре некоторых видео, в коде `css` при использование имени класса или `ID` были знаки `>` и `~`.

В интернете нигде не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос. Хотелось бы узнать точный ответ зачем эти знаки в коде.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B ну или более общедоступным языком и другими "значками" здесь — https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css - тут тоже про Селекторы и их комбинации есть

Answer (score 1):

Элемент subsequent-sibling combinator состоит из «тильды» (U + 007E, ~) - это символ ~ , разделяющий две последовательности простых селекторов. Элементы, представленные двумя последовательностями, имеют одного и того же родителя в дереве документа, и элемент, представленный первой последовательностью, предшествует (не обязательно непосредственно) элементу, представленному второй последовательностью. [Подробнее..](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators)